# Parentheses for subshell don't work when stored in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, parentheses, subshell

The command:

```
( echo 1 )
```

works fine when I input it in the command line but if I store it as a variable and call it, it gives the error:

```
(echo: command not found
```

Code:

```
input="( echo 1 )"
$input
```

Why doesn't it evaluate the parentheses the same way and put it into a subshell when I call it this way?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). An unquoted expansion only goes through two stages of parsing (field-splitting and glob expansion); this is true for very good reasons (it would be much harder to write secure code in bash otherwise). The linked FAQ goes into substantial detail, including discussion of best-practices for cases where you might otherwise want to store code in a variable.

Comment: You can't put such commands in a variable. In fact, putting commands in variables is prone to failure. Variables hold _data_, not _commands!_ if you want to store commands somewhere for future use, use a _function._

Comment: BTW, your code and your error don't line up. You'd be getting `(: command not found` if you used the exact code given here. Do be sure to actually copy/paste the code in your question *exactly as asked* to avoid such situations in the future, in cases where those differences might actually matter.

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed in full detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

An unquoted expansion goes through only two stages of shell parsing: Field-splitting, and glob expansion. Thus, `( echo 1 )` is first split into fields: `(`, `echo`, `1`, and `)`; each is expanded as a glob (moot, as none of them are glob expansions); and then they're run as a command: `(` is invoked, with the first argument `echo`, the second argument `1`, and the third argument `)`.

The Right Way to store code is in a function:

```
# best-practices approach
input() ( echo 1; )
input
```

...or, if you want to make it more explicit to a human reader that you *really* want a subshell and weren't using parens rather than braces by error or habit:

```
# same, but more explicit about intent
input() { (echo 1); }
input
```

...if not possible, one can use `eval` (but be wary of the caveats given in [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)):

```
# avoid this approach if at all possible
input="( echo 1 )"
eval "$input"
```

---

If the real reason you're building a command in a string is to parameterize its contents, use an array instead:

```
input_args=( 1 )                    # define an array
input() ( echo "${input_args[@]}" ) # use that array in a function (if needed)

# add things according to conditional logic as appropriate
if (( 2 > 1 )); then
  input_args+=( "possible argument here" )
fi

# call the function, or just use the array directly, such as: (echo "$(input_args[@]}" )
input
```

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses are shell syntax.

To *reflect* syntax which is stored in variable back into the shell for processing, you must use the `eval` command.

Merely interpolating the value of the variable into a command line doesn't trigger `eval` evaluation of the syntax. That would be an unwanted intrusion of eval, which would cause all sorts of problems.

For instance, consider this:

```
arg="(parenthesized)"
somecommand $arg
```

We just want `somecommand` to be invoked with the character string `(parenthesized)` as its argument; we don't want to run a subshell. That sort of implicit eval would turn harmless data into live code, creating a security hole, not to mention a coding nightmare to try to avoid it.

The rules for how `$arg` is treated are independent of position; the expansion happens the same way even if `$arg` is the first element in the command line:

```
$arg foo
```

Parameter substitution turns `$arg` into the text `(parenthesized)` and then that is tried as a command, not as a shell syntax.

To execute the piece of shell script stored in `input`, use:

```
eval "$input"
```

You could also do it like this:

```
input="echo 1"       # no parentheses

/bin/sh -c "$input"  # run in subshell explicitly
```

Of course, the subshell approach feeds the code fragment to the same shell which is executing the surrounding script, whereas here we chose the `/bin/sh` which could be different from the invoking shell, or have a different behavior even if it is a symlink to the same shell.

Comment: Since `command` is a builtin, using it as a standin for some-random-other-command is a bit confusing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That is an excellent point, sir; it must be fixed.